# Maven: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1

Tags: java, linux, maven, jboss

I have configured maven 3.2.2 and JBoss EAP 6.1 in centos 6.1;I have installed these things in a remote vm machine and accessing them using PuTTY

I have tried to run a quick start program helloworld-jms program using the command

```
`mvn clean compile exec:java`
```

it is giving the error saying

```
`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-22T03:32:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/171M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1 (/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.1.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.1.1.jar): error in opening zip file`
```

i thought problem is with the proxy settings and i went to /root/.m2/settings.xml and changed the proxy settings also still this problem is remaining

I have also removed the repository under .m2 folder and clean installed maven using the command

```
`mvn -U clean install`
```

it gave me a message build successful; and new repository appeared

again I tried to run the program with the command `mvn clean compile exec:java`

I couldn't locate the error

Please help me what could be the error and how to solve it; I have checked earlier posts and tried the best I could

Comment: Can you post the POM file?

Comment: The usage of `mvn -U` will not change anything cause it's related to snapshot version. Furthermore why are you using such an extreme old version of exec-maven-plugin? And yes you have problems with your proxy settings etc. Apart from the things before you haven't understood the [build life cylce. If you call `mvn clean install` everything has been built and tests have run so it does not make sense to call `mvn clean compile` cause parts of the life cycle will run again. The second time you should only need to do `mvn exec:java`.

Comment: which pom you are expecting ??

Comment: when I try to compile the program usignt he command `mvn -U clean compile`
it is getting compiled successfully but when I try to execute it

`mvn exec:java` it is giving the error..along witht he above mentiioend error I am also getting the warning saying failed checksum for 

 `Checksum validation failed, expected 6e2c6d57c69e40eba5b1b1e8b9b86fd464d91043 but is b39eccc80ac4aae5cfbf26014dce6f294bb673cc for http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.jar`

what I should change please help me

Comment: Is there any repository other than  
`http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/`

Comment: First, have you tried updating your Maven Exec plugin to something current like 1.3.1?  Second, you still haven't posted your POM file.  I at least need to see the maven-exec section.  Edit your original post and include it.